# Retrieve directory/ Files from remote AWS VMs in ASP.NET MVC by User Name-Password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 5 application in which I want to retrieve the Image/Audio/Video from other server(s).

I googled and find some result including use of `FTPWebRequest` or `NetworkShareAccesser` to access from same domain computers but I don't want to create domain and add computers to it, rather all computers are independent VMs from AWS.

Most available solutions are either done with same domain VMs and that is OK in their case but I want to retrieve files from VMs but using IP/UserName/Password?

Comment: If you can access file of any aws machine just by using username and password aws would go bankrupt on security issues.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I meant without putting computers on same domain